# Button that Shows Full Information for the Selected Row of a Table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I need some help in php. I'm fairly new to the language, though I'm using it on Wamp for a website, which should display a table with an ID and a submit button in each row that when clicked, should display the information for that specific row only. The syntax that I came up with has one problem, it shows the information for all the rows instead of just the one clicked. The code is as follows:

```
<?php
  print "<table>";
```

Table Headers

```
    print "<tr>";
      print "<th>ID</th>";
      print "<th>Click to View Row Info</th>";
    print "</tr>";
```

Table Contents (ID & Button in 5 rows)

```
  for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    print "<tr>";
      print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"Popup.php\">";
      print "<td>";
      print "<input name=\"$i\" type=\"text\" value=\"";
      echo $i;
      print "\"/>";
      print "</td>";


      print "<td>";

      print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"View Row\" /></form>";
      print "</td>";

    print "</tr>";
  }
```

Popup.php Display Code Snippet

```
  $sub=$i;

  for ($i=0; $i<=$sub; $i++){
  print "The ID for this row is: ";
  echo $i; 
  }
?>
```

Popup.php is a separate file that receives the form variables and displays it. If I could get some assistance with this I would be most grateful. If anything is unclear about my question please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form needs to be outside of the loop (and should be outside of the tbale as well)
Also, change the input name so like this
so this

```
print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"Popup.php\">";

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    print "<tr>";

      print "<td>";
      print "<input name=\name[$i]\" type=\"text\" value=\"";
      echo $i;
      print "\"/>";
      print "</td>";


      print "<td>";

      print "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"View Row\" /></form>";
      print "</td>";

    print "</tr>";
  }
```

THen in popup.php change it to

```
 foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$value)
    print "The value for $key is: $value";
```

Comment: Each row contains a form, so the form should be inside the loop.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly, thank you. I have another question though, is it possible to assign the id variable to the button?

Answer (score 0):

First, use a constant for the `name attribute` of the input element for the ID

```
print "<input name='val' type=\"text\" value=\"";
```

Then change this line

```
$sub=$i;
```

to

$sub = $_POST['val'];

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Your answer helped me greatly.